# I have to enter twice for >,<,= to indent in VIM

Tags: vim

I am using vim on Ubuntu 10.10.

In order to indent code, I enter >. But I have to do it twice.

Other command, like < and = are the same. I have to do it twice.

Is it normal? Of I should change something?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the normal operation.  The first `>` starts the indent command.  The second `>` commits the indent command.  What you put in between defines what you want to indent (defaults to 1 line):

- `>>` is indent one line.
- `>5>` is indent 5 lines
- `>G` is indent to the end of the file.

The `>G` doesn't need a trailing `>` to commit the command as the G command is a *terminating* command already.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to indent a line say 3 levels, you can use the "." motion to repeat the last action after indenting.

Eg:

```
>>..
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked better for me that the answer marked as accepted from Majenko.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to abbreviate this, you can create a macro that indents just the current line or some other preset value. For example`:map <tab> >1>`

Answer (score 1):

I use`>}` to indent a paragraph (a chunk of code up to the next empty line)